# windows 10 ~ Microsoft Office professional 10 ~ OneNote ScreenShot

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, onenote

[SOLUTION: There are two versions of OneNote. A free version (comes with Windows 10 and a purchased version (purchased; comes with Office). The Free Version of OneNote doesn't seem to have all features that the Purchased version of OneNote has. See Answer below for more information]

[Initial Problem Question] There seems to be no way to create a screen shot shortcut or OneNote if you have oneNote 2010 on Windows 10. All instructions I find seem to pertain to a 15.0 folder, not the 14.0 folder
[How to get quickkey for onenote screenshot on win 10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/screen-clipping-shortcut-onenote-windows-8-1).

I don't understand. In Windows 7 OneNote was awesome. win+S for screenshot, nice UI layout, but in Windows 10 oneNote seems to have been rendered useless.

[image]

**FOLLOW UP:**
There are apparently two version of OneNote on my Windows 10 OS. Please see the pictures below. The OneNote2010 which is the first OneNote icon in each of the two pictures works wonderfully. I can even get the screenShot to work without having to go into the registry. The OneNote at the bottom of both pictures is horrible. I can't stand it. What is this bad version of oneNOte? I found the OneNote i was having all the trouble with (the 'bad' one) by using the cortona search and typing in 'OneNote'. I found the good version of OneNote by clicking on the 'Start' menu, then going to 'All Apps' | 'Microsoft Office 2010' | 'OnNote'. This one works great ... like it always did ... same UI ... same shortcut keys, everything. Why did they do this?

[image: one note picture 1]

[image: one note picture 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this a bit more now that I have more time. I thought the OneNote that I has called the 'bad' version (in initial question) might have been a trial that doesn't have all features which just does not get overwritten/deleted even when/after the Licensed version is installed.

It turns out there there is actually a version of OneNote that comes with Windows8 and Windows10. You can read all about the differences at this website:
[Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Frequently-Asked-Questions-about-OneNote-cb66061d-3af3-4c29-b340-d687bc915f91?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

The one that comes with windows (not a part of microsoft office) seems to be a 'light' version of oneNote. If you have never used oneNote before, don't base your opinion of oneNote on the app version that comes with windows. The full (non-light) version of OneNote that comes with the actual microsoft office package is a great tool.

I do not believe there is a screenshot capability with the app version of OneNote (someone correct me if I am wrong). I added one last screen shot to show what the two different oneNote icons look like when you search for them via Cortona (below). The icon which says 'Microsoft OneNote 2010' is the full blown version of OneNote. The one that just says OneNote is a light-weight version/app that comes with Windows.

[image]

Comment: Why you use Onenote 2010 instead of newer (and free) version which does perfectly support win10?

Comment: They both seem to function as they are supposed to. However, if you do not realize that you are using OneNote the app instead of Microsoft OneNote 2010, you will think it is broken when in actuality you are not using the OneNote software you think you are using. I wish they would have called the OneNote app that comes with Window 10, OneNoteLight to differentiate it. When i saw the name, I thought it was the same software. Even when i started investigating I thought it was just a name change for marketing purposes (we do that with our software sometimes).

Comment: the free app does not seem to have all the capabilities that the version you pay for (the ones that comes with microsoft office). it is a nice app if you understand that you aren't using the full blown version (ie: expecting more than what is offered in the lightweight app version).

Comment: The free, full "desktop" version (2016) is supposed to have all capabilities of the Office OneNote. Which capability does not work for you? It is indeed confusing that they have the other ("app") version in Win10.

Comment: screen shot. additionally the UI is not the same. Are you a developer for OneNote?

Comment: watered down UI

Comment: additionally there are no HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry settings for the 'app'.  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\OneNote\Options\Other

Comment: see following website: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_other/onenote-screen-clipping-tool-hotkeys-in-windows-10/f454aa9d-c295-478c-8496-4146c1ba5876